# Антивирус жалуется на любой файл скачаный через программу

Tags: python, python-3.x, вирусы, антивирус

Есть программа:

```
import smtplib
import requests


def download(url):
        get_response = requests.get(url)
        file_name = url.split("/")[-1]

        with open(file_name, "wb") as out_file:
                out_file.write(get_response.content)


download("https://buffy.mlpforums.com/imageproxy/kitten.jpg")
```

Её цель - скачать из интернета картинку. Когда я запускаю её с расширением `.py` всё работает корректно, картинка скачавается, но когда я делаю из неё `.exe` с помощью `pyinstaller file.py --onefile` windows выдаёт сообщение, что невозможно открыть файл, так как он может содержать вирусы. Как я понимаю, антивирус жалуется на сам факт работы с файлами, а не на то, какие файлы и что с ними происходит.

Программа должна работать на любом ПК, а так как питон есть не у всех, должна быть в формате `.exe`, но заставлять пользователя отрубать антивирус для работы программы - не вариант. Как это обойти?

Изменено:

Дополнительно прогнал файлы через `virustotal.com`. На `.py` файл не среагировал ни один антивирус, на `.exe` - 13 из 68.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pyinstaller+virus